# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

Использую Python 3.5.2

Есть код, который работал примерно месяц и до сегодняшнего дня

**код не изменялся**

```
token = '453645645332454664553453454353454' #в примере недействительный токен
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

При запуске получаю `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Похоже на ошибку JSONDecodeError. У вас request.body начал давать пустую строку. Если код действительно не менялся, то изменения произошли на стороне сервера. Подробнее сказать нельзя по этому огрызку кода.

Comment: @Александр да, спасибо. Через некоторое время все исчезло